# In windows, stopping postgres service causes node to crash with "error : terminating connection due to administrator command"

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, postgresql, express

Scenario 1: postgres service not running. node start. rest calls times out => no issues

Scenario 2: postgres service not running. node start. postgres service start. rest calls work => no issues

Scenario 3: postgres service not running. node start. postgres service start. rest calls work. postgres service stop => node crash.

Stack trace when this happens is given below:

> error: terminating connection due to administrator command
>       at Connection.parseE (...\express.js\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:553:11)
>       at Connection.parseMessage (...\express.js\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:378:19)
>       at Socket. (...\express.js\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:119:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:594:20)

I am using Postgres Pool with the following config:

```
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'sampleDB',
    password: 'password',
    port: 5432,
    max: 1,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
    connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
})
```

How do I handle this case so that node won't crash and can go back to Scenario-1 and then move to Scenario-2 ?

Comment: Catch the error.

The appropriate SQLSTATEs are `57014`, `57P01` and `57P02`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks. I have couple of Questions related to this. 1: How did you get the codes? 2: Is this an acceptable approach in a production environment?

Comment: `java.sql.SQLException` has a `getSQLState()` method. This is the best way to distinguish between different errors. Parsing the message text is a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After going through the documentation of node-postgres([link](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool#-code-pool-on-39-error-39-err-error-client-client-gt-void-gt-void-code-)), I figured out a way to capture this error and avoid node crash.

```
pool.on('error', (err, client) => {
    console.log('postgres connection error : ' + err)
})
```

Adding the above code will allow node to handle the error and not crash.